# ios - cellForRowAtIndex method of tableView functions very odd

Tags: ios

My problem is as follows: At the first startup of my app the `cellforRowAtIndex` method doesn't load all items of an array, although the `numberOfRowsInSection` method gives right number of items, exp: `numberOfRowsInSection` method give 4 items but `cellforRowAtIndex` method loads only 2 items of these.

But at the second startup loads all items correctly, I hadn't found the reason of this problem, its just so annoying.

I have loaded all objects from an SSL Encrypted `HTTPConnection` to an array. I have debugged a few times with breakpoints already, but nothing found. The array is loaded with all objects already but cannot be loaded by `cellforRowAtIndex` method somehow.

Comment: post some code..

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that the table is updated after the array ends loading.

or just call `[UITableView ReloadData];` after your array is fully loaded.